# Plot Twist (variety cryptic)

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-crosswords

<sup>This is an entry into [the 36th Fortnightly Topic Challenge: "Twisted Classics".](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/fortnightly-topic-challenge-36-twisted-classics-1)</sup>

---

Each clue/answer pair in this puzzle has been affected by one of these types of plot twist:

- 28 of the clues have wordplay resulting in a string with a "**red herring**" of two extra letters (always adjacent to each other). Record each pair of letters (in either order) for later.
- A few answers will have "**false protagonists**". Put these false characters in their logical places; then, if the false character's value is *n*, circle the *n*th letter from the start and end of the clue. When read in clue order (left to right in each clue), these circled letters will give you **step 1**.
- Some clues will have a "**reversal of fortune**" somewhere in their clue. If this reversal happens at the m-th word, take the m-th letter of the clue for **step 2**. (Hyphenated words are one word, not multiple.)
- An **unreliable narrator** has added an extra detail to the remaining clues in the form of a single word. The first and last letters of these words form **step 3** and **step 4**, respectively.

Once you've puzzled out all the clues' plot twists, use the extra pairs to locate specific cells in the grid, and shade those cells. The *pattern of shaded cells* will be another "plot twist" in a very different form; the location where it comes from is "piece 1".

Next, follow steps 1 through 4, and you will add *another* "twist" to this puzzle. Three words will be revealed: when the object they describe is written out fully, it is "piece 2".

Finally, examine the shaded cells. One fully-shaded column (which may be a bit distorted by now) is a *very* informal phrase I might say to describe the puzzle after steps 1-4 have been carried out. Reading *all* the shaded cells in the proper order (which is also probably distorted) gives a phrase that *you* might say to describe the puzzle after steps 1-4. This phrase is *also* cryptic wordplay for **a final 3-word phrase** that describes the puzzle as a whole.

[image]

**ACROSS**
**1:** Metallic element created by Zulu rival of Forbes
**3:** Medieval weapon made by a male cat and a bird of prey
**11:** Patch of ground's place for a pan
**14:** Courageous trap for cure
**17:** Seaweed now having edge
**18:** Brazilian state's cooler judges
**20:** Speaker from Apple device stolen by sextet
**21:** Nimble alumni hide soldier in brown beverage
**23:** Again, starts up vortices with aliens
**24:** Klansman obsessed with fragments of Twin Towers
**25:** Alternative to stereo, just in Missouri
**26:** Uninspiring elements of master ski lessons
**27:** Loop consideration from Hulk director cut short
**31:** Sound of Dixieland's seductiveness: first sign of evil
**33:** Stumbles around, having time for those putting on a show
**36:** With TeX, adjust spacing and remove "e" to get "seagull"
**37:** Cries for "eternal spirit" deception, less politely
**40:** Brief images before stream similar to works with Mary cradling Jesus
**43:** Elk wanders with herds, losing leader
**44:** Body-bending exercise with interminable lag just after greeting
**45:** Spots of actinium put next to empty neckerchief and yarmulke
**46:** Brief facts of lower bound with no origin
**47:** Released a pleasant smell to the audience
**48:** Crosses having soap ingredient? Absolutely!
**49:** Emetic made from trimmings of nutmeg, zinnia, ulmus, and epigaea, with  collection of 27 books
**50:** Match that's automatically now, near early evening

**DOWN**
**1:** Essentially, Captain Underpants is one from Karafuto
**2:** From Yukon: also, not then having era (or so I hear)
**3:** Graphics package with a couple of errors is a piece of cake
**4:** At first, one very grand area seemingly is a place of refuge
**5:** Picture of trams not having front two pieces
**6:** That man's honeycomb she lost
**7:** Burnt remains of Christmas near hospital
**8:** More recently, authors of Q form a faction
**9:** Crustaceans' thousand arms and two left feet
**10:** Collector of dust returned deer
**11:** Fight, when energy becomes heart, turns into a pool of liquid
**12:** For instance, interrupting unknown person's big head
**13:** Makes less distinct avocado and Chinese food without hesitation
**15:** Modernize, fixing up "fey ring" decal with time
**16:** Gives wrecked car a pull again, after an accident with smashed towers
**19:** Cartoonist or animator's animal found in accelerator
**22:** Solve anagram: "laxest" and "exalts"
**23:** Now aged, walked over footpath again without end
**26:** Composer's wear, when a farthing becomes a shilling
**27:** Burning of boat with us aboard
**28:** Even after admitting extra weight, chowed down
**29:** Be jealous of technique with dash (pieces towards the back) of ivy
**30:** Dispose of loops being used as recaps for author Eliot
**32:** Disastrous gala for sea urchin plant
**34:** Elvish script missing final two characters leaves just under a dozen
**35:** Psychologically manipulated pace
**37:** Perceive reverse-engineered strap
**38:** Utah college with high class renowned in the UK (abbr.)
**39:** Partially knew jaunty odor from France
**40:** Quiet, pale fathers
**41:** Cooler for breakfast beverage
**42:** Nepal's money sounds like something that might go with a buck

Comment: Solving is going on in a Google sheet; see TSL chat for the link.

Comment: You made a rather complicated one this time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Solution by Gareth McCaughan, Volatility and possibly some anonymous others; thanks to Volatility for making a spreadsheet in which we could collaborate. In the end I think I did most of it, which is why I'm posting this, but by no means all. Go and find some answers written by Volatility and upvote them if you like this one.)

(I'm not going to bother with spoiler markup. This is far enough down the page that if you don't want to be spoiled you can just not read it.)

**The plot twists**

*Red herring* clues are described clearly and explicitly in the rubric: the wordplay leads not to the defined answer but to that plus two adjacent extra letters. The version with extra letters is not usually a word.

*False protagonist* clues, of which there turn out to be four, need their first letter removing before entry (kinda). More about those later.

*Reversal of fortune* clues contain one word that needs to be reversed (always yielding a new word) before solving the clue.

*Unreliable narrator* clues are as described in the rubric: one word in the clue needs to be removed before solving.

**The clues and their solutions**

Here are the clues, in order, annotated H(erring), P(rotagonist), R(eversal), U(nreliable), with clue-modifications and solutions shown:

*Across*
**1:** *P* Metallic element created by Zulu rival of Forbes `[Z]INC`
**3:** *U* [Medieval] weapon made by a male cat and a bird of prey `TOMAHAWK`
**11:** *R* Patch of ground's place for a [pan<] `BED`
**14:** *R* Courageous [trap<] for cure `AGE`
**17:** *H* Seaweed now having edge `NORI[MW]`
**18:** *H* Brazilian state's cooler judges `ACRE[FS]`
**20:** *R* Speaker from Apple device stolen by sextet `SIRI[GX]`
**21:** *U* Nimble [alumni] hide soldier in brown beverage `AGILE`
**23:** *H* Again, starts up vortices with aliens `[GY]RESETS`
**24:** *U* [Klansman] obsessed with fragments of Twin Towers `INTO`
**25:** *H* Alternative to stereo, just in Missouri `MON[LY]O`
**26:** *H* Uninspiring elements of master ski lessons `STER[SK]ILE`
**27:** *R* [Loop<] consideration from Hulk director cut short `ANGLE`
**31:** *R* Sound of Dixieland's seductiveness: first sign of [evil<] `DRAWL`
**33:** *H* Stumbles around, having time for those putting on a show `STA[GT]GERS`
**36:** *H* With TeX, adjust spacing and remove "e" to get "seagull" `TE[XK]RN`
**37:** *H* Cries for "eternal spirit" deception, less politely `SO[UL]BS`
**40:** *H* Brief images before stream similar to works with Mary cradling Jesus `PI[XJ]ETAS`
**43:** *U* [Elk] wanders with herds, losing leader `DROVES`
**44:** *R* Body-bending exercise with interminable [lag<] just after greeting `YOGA`
**45:** *H* Spots of actinium put next to empty neckerchief and yarmulke `ACN[FY]E`
**46:** *R* Brief facts of lower bound with [no<] origin `INFO`
**47:** *P* Released a pleasant smell to the audience `[S]ENT`
**48:** *H* Crosses having soap ingredient? Absolutely! `[XL]YES`
**49:** *H* Emetic made from trimmings of nutmeg, zinnia, ulmus, and epigaea, with collection of 27 books `N[GZ]AUSEANT`
**50:** *R* Match that's automatically [now<], near early evening `BYE`

*Down*
**1:** *P* Essentially, Captain Underpants is one from Karafuto `[A]INU`
**2:** *R* From Yukon: also, not then having [era<] (or so I hear) `NORTHERN`
**3:** *H* Graphics package with a couple of errors is a piece of cake `TI[KZ]ER`
**4:** *H* At first, one very grand area seemingly is a place of refuge `O[VG]ASIS`
**5:** *R* Picture of [trams<] not having front two pieces `ART`
**6:** *U* That man's [honeycomb] she lost `HES`
**7:** *H* Burnt remains of Christmas near hospital `[XM]ASH`
**8:** *H* More recently, authors of Q form a faction `W[UM]ING`
**9:** *H* Crustaceans' thousand arms and two left feet `KRI[GS]LL`
**10:** *R* Collector of dust returned [deer<] `BIN`
**11:** *H* Fight, when energy becomes heart, turns into a pool of liquid `BAT[TL]H`
**12:** *H* For instance, interrupting unknown person's big head `[WH]EGO`
**13:** *U* Makes less distinct [avocado] and Chinese food without hesitation `DIMS`
**15:** *R* Modernize, fixing up "fey ring" [decal<] with time `GENTRIFY`
**16:** *P* Gives wrecked car a pull again, after an accident with smashed towers `[R]ETOWS`
**19:** *R* Cartoonist or animator's [animal<] found in accelerator `CEL`
**22:** *U* Solve anagram: ["laxest"] and "exalts" `LOVES`
**23:** *U* Now aged, walked over [footpath] again without end `RETRO`
**26:** *H* Composer's wear, when a farthing becomes a shilling `SATI[GU]E`
**27:** *H* Burning of boat with us aboard `AR[KU]SON`
**28:** *H* Even after admitting extra weight, chowed down `E[VF]ATEN`
**29:** *U* Be jealous of [technique] with dash (pieces towards the back) of ivy `ENVY`
**30:** *R* Dispose of loops being used as [recaps<] for author Eliot `TOSS`
**32:** *U* Disastrous gala for sea [urchin] plant `ALGA`
**34:** *H* Elvish script missing final two characters leaves just under a dozen `TEN[GW]`
**35:** *H* Psychologically manipulated pace `GA[SL]IT`
**37:** *R* Perceive reverse-engineered [strap<] `SEE`
**38:** *U* Utah college with high class [renowned] in the UK (abbr.) `BYU`
**39:** *H* Partially knew jaunty odor from France `[WJ]EAU`
**40:** *H* Quiet, pale fathers `PAS[HY]`
**41:** *H* Cooler for breakfast beverage `[JU]ICE`
**42:** *U* [Nepal's] money sounds like something that might go with a buck `DOE`

**The false protagonists**

We begin here rather than with the red herrings because the false protagonists need to be put in their proper places first. The false-protagonist clues are the across clues at top and bottom left, and the down clues at left and right top. Their first letters need to be written *outside the grid*, and now we see the top of the grid with labels A at left and R at right, and the left side with labels  Z at top and S at bottom. And the number of spaces in between is just right to fill in B..Q at the top and Y..T on the left, so that the whole alphabet is used to label the rows and columns of the grid.

**The red herrings**

Recall that the rubric indicates that the order of the letter pairs in these doesn't matter (which is just as well, because for STAGERS it could be either way). And notice that each letter pair contains one letter in the range A..R and one in the range S..Z. Treat these as coordinates, using the row and column labels we just applied, and shade in the resulting cells. This would be a good point to display the resulting grid:

[image]

Unless one is so benighted an ignoramus as not to be fluent in Chinese [note: your present author is a benighted ignoramus], it is obvious that the shaded cells form the (simplified) Chinese character 拧 one of whose meanings is ... **twist**. (As Deusovi has pointed out in TSL chat, this means that what we have just done is to "plot *twist*". Nice title drop.) OK then. We'll return to these shaded cells later.

Oh, and of course "piece 1" is `CHINA`. We'll return to that later, too.

**Step 1: The false protagonists, again**

Translating the letters Z,S,A,R into numbers in the obvious A1Z26 fashion and counting from the ends of the clues involved (and, of course, noting that when the rubric says "left to right" it means left to right after that counting; some of the clues are not very long) yields our first instruction: `CUT ME OUT`.

So we should take that grid and cut around its edges to get an 18x8 rectangle.

**Step 2: The reversals of fortune**

Counting as the rubric instructs yields our second instruction: `FOLD BACK CENTER`. So "mountain-fold" along the horizontal line that divides the grid into two equal parts. Our centerfold model is now an 18x4 rectangle with letters on both front and back.

**Steps 3 and 4: The unreliable narrators**

The first letters of the spurious words say `MAKE HALF TURN`. The last letters say `LINK BOTH ENDS`. So, as the discerning reader may have been suspecting for a while, with a suitably placed **twist** we now make our grid into a Möbius strip.

This allows new words to be created where the ends are attached. The rubric says that we should find three; in fact there are at least four. But `YESTER` is altogether too 23d a word for our tastes, so let's 30d it. There still remain `LETTER`, `TWENTY` and `FOUR`.

So piece 2 is `X`. In fact it turns out that it's better to make it `EX`.

**The shaded cells, again**

Column "G" has all its cells shaded. They say, if we are sufficiently broad-minded to let them, `ARTED BY U`. Yup, we sure arted pretty good.

What is the proper order to read all the cells in? Well, since this puzzle is only for those fluent in Chinese, the obvious thing [note: I had no idea until Volatility suggested it] is to read them in the One True Stroke Order that your bamboo-and-tiger-hair brush traverses when writing the character formed by the cells. This plainly [note: I had no idea until Volatility told me] ends up saying `CREATED BY US TAKING IN THE PIECES`. I have to confess that I don't think I would say those words in order to describe the puzzle after steps 1-4; so much the worse for me.

**The final wordplay**

"Created by us" -> `MADEUS`, obviously. The pieces are `CHINAEX`, as previously explained. The one takes in the other to yield `MACHINA EX DEUS`. Ex Deusovi, that is. And we're done.

**A few final comments**

Hats off to Deusovi: that was a pretty densely packed puzzle! It was fun to solve, though for some shorter answers the red-herring mechanism made it difficult to be confident of having found the right solution.

Thanks to Deusovi for pointing out (in TSL chat) how I was failing to understand 20a. I have made an appropriate minor correction above.